# How to put google credential json in ENV variable for production?

Tags: environment-variables, google-cloud-storage, elixir, production

I cant find how to inject the google Json credential file into an ENV variable for production. The dependency I use is called goth for elixir, and I am supposed to feed it with those credentials on app startup.

For the json, I encoded Google's file with Poison.encode!() and use it as a text in my ENV variables.

in my dev config file : **it works**

```
config :goth, json: {:system, "GCP_CREDENTIALS"}
```

in my prod config file : **it doens't work** and I keep getting a syntax error at the beginning of the json

```
config :goth, json: {:system, '${GCP_CREDENTIALS}'}
```

Any suggestion or anybody who made this working and could share about his experience ?

Comment: `'${GCP_CREDENTIALS}'` is a charlist, not a string. In Elixir double quotes and single quotes have absolutely different meaning. Also, it’s unclear why would you put a dollar sign and curly braces there; `{:system, _}` expects an environment variable name _as a binary_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the goth README it looks like you have a couple options.

1. Load the file into the config via: `config :goth,
   json: "path/to/google/json/creds.json" |> File.read!`
2. Have the entire contents of the file in an env var and do: config :goth, json: {:system, "GCP_CREDENTIALS"}
3. Via your own module: `config :goth, config_module: MyConfigMod`
   and then

```
defmodule MyConfigMod do
  use Goth.Config

  def init(config) do
    {:ok, Keyword.put(config, :json, System.get_env("MY_GCP_JSON_CREDENTIALS"))}
  end
end
```

I could be wrong about the "${GCP_CREDENTIALS}" in the config, but the only place I have seen "${...}" used before is in distillery when you use `REPLACE_OS_VARS=true`. If you are indeed using distillery, then you do not need the {:system, "${GCP_CREDENTIALS}"} tuple, you can just put `config :goth, json: "${GCP_CREDENTIALS}"` where the `GCP_CREDENTIALS` env var contains the contents of the credentials json file.

Source of examples: https://github.com/peburrows/goth#installation

Distillery docs: https://hexdocs.pm/distillery/runtime-configuration.html#vm-args